# Can't get individual references to views when inflating multiple instances

Tags: android, android-layout, layout-inflater, android-inflate

My intent is to inflate numerous instances of the same view on a LinearLayout, and then modify their views accordingly. However, whenever I inflate a view multiple times, I always end up with the same reference to the first inflated view.

Simplified example:

```
    View v = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.inflatable_layout,rootLinearLayout,true);
    TextView t = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text1);
    t.setText("Foo");
    View v2 = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.inflatable_layout,rootLinearLayout,true);
    TextView t2 = (TextView) v2.findViewById(R.id.text1);
    t2.setText("Bar");
```

By doing this, I end up with two inflated views. However, the first view's TextView contains "Bar", and the second one unaltered.

Is there a way to be able to maintain reference to the views I inflate individually?

Answer (score 1):

To solve your problem, just change:

```
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.inflatable_layout,rootLinearLayout,true);
```

to

```
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.inflatable_layout,rootLinearLayout,false);
rootLinearLayout.addView(v1);
```

Note that you now have to add the view manualy to your layout.

(Do the same for v2)

This way you should receive two different references.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
View v = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.inflatable_layout,null); // Note the null replacing the "ViewGroup"
TextView t = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text1);
t.setText("Foo");
View v2 =    getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.inflatable_layout,null); // Note the null replacing the "ViewGroup"
TextView t2 = (TextView) v2.findViewById(R.id.text1);
t2.setText("Bar");

// Manually append each layout to your linear layout.
```

I think this should work, as no root is defined

Comment: That should crash, as you are saying you want to add the view as a child of `null`.

Comment: No, I think you have to explicitly pass `false`, and pass in the actual desired parent. I never use `true` for the last parameter personally, and I had forgotten how it worked. Quoting [the docs, this version of `inflate()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html#inflate%28int,%20android.view.ViewGroup,%20boolean%29): "Returns the root View of the inflated hierarchy. If root was supplied and attachToRoot is true, this is root; otherwise it is the root of the inflated XML file."

Comment: I just tried passing null as the parent and then adding the views with AddView(v), and got the desired behavior, but also got a "Avoid passing null as the view root" warning. Passing the parent (rootLinearLayout in this case) and setting the last parameter to false, then adding the views manually through AddView(v) also produces the desired behavior, and without the warning.